# how to get all file name from System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.IO.FileInfo] variable in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, file

```
var files =  DirInfo.GetFiles()
                    .Where(file => (file.CreationTime >= startDate && file.CreationTime <= endDate));
```

How can fetch all files name from files variable in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = files.Select (file => file.Name);
```

to print you can do the following:

```
foreach (var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("File name : {0}", name));
```

Comment: I want to print file name but instead of that it prints System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.IO.FileInfo,System.String].

Comment: How to print all file name on console ?

Comment: It's Working. Thank you so much. @David

Answer (score 0):

If your query giving the file list correctly then attach this `.Select(x=>new FileInfo(x).Name)` along with your query. Or you can try likethe following:

```
   var files= Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users")
              .Where(f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime >= startDate && 
              new FileInfo(f).CreationTime <= endDate).Select(x=>new FileInfo(x).Name);
```